# SAPUI5 'Mismatched anonymous define()' Error rendering sap.viz Chart

Tags: javascript, data-binding, sapui5, sap-fiori, web-ide

i am trying to create a sap.viz.ui5.Donut Chart, the first time i want to fill it with Data i get the Error '`Mismatched anonymous define() module: function ()`'.

My XML-View looks like:

```
<viz:ui5.Donut width="100%">
    <viz:title>
        <viz:ui5.types.Title text="t"/>
    </viz:title>
    <viz:dataset>
        <viz:ui5.data.FlattenedDataset data="{chartData>/data}">
            <viz:dimensions>
                <viz:ui5.data.DimensionDefinition axis="1" name="Creator" value="{Creator}"/>
            </viz:dimensions>
            <viz:measures>
                <viz:ui5.data.MeasureDefinition name="Count" value="{Count}"/>
            </viz:measures>
        </viz:ui5.data.FlattenedDataset>
    </viz:dataset>
</viz:ui5.Donut>
```

And my Controller has the following code:

```
        var oModel = new JSONModel();
        oModel.loadData("../resources/DiagramData.json", "", false);
        this.getView().setModel(oModel, "chartData");
```

The second time i run the code it works, does anyone know how to fix that Problem?

Answer (score 0):

Where do you initialize your model?

Have hou tried loading the model earlier? Perhaps in your component.js? It would not make much sense, but it would be worth trying anyways.

You could also try setting the model to the core instead of the view. `sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel, "chartData")` or directly to the control. The last would probably not solve it seen your issue.

Comment: I load the data on a buttonPress, so well after the `onAfterRendering`-Method, but the data depends on user input. If i load the data immediately it works just fine.

Comment: Sorry my reply took so long, what if you set the binding at the beginning and make sure the webservice returns no results. Then when user has provided input you can bind again.